# find out which column has a particular string and return the column number

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a database table consisting of strings... I need to search for a particular string in the table row by row and return the column number where that string appears... I am using mysql database..

my table is of the form

QID Question Choice1 Choice2 Choice3 Choice4

I am given two strings... first string will be found under Question column and second string will be found in Choice1 or Choice2 or Choice3 or Choice4 ... I need to find the column number of the column which has my second string ...

Can someone please tell me what to do ?

Comment: please post your table structure

Comment: That sounds like an odd database setup.
Can you explain the use case?

Comment: Doesn't seem right. DB structure, please.

Comment: QID Question  Choice1 Choice2 Choice3 Choice4 ... This is my table structure ... Given a string, i have to check whether the string appears in Choice1,choice2,choice3 or choice4 column ...

Comment: This is why we don't do "choice1,choice2,choice3..."  It violates 1st normal form, and even if you don't care about the theory, the fact is it makes it a b**ch to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ugly response but your question is a bit weird.

```
SELECT COALESCE(IF(col1='thestring',1,NULL), IF(col2='thestring',2,NULL), IF(col3='thestring',3,NULL) ....) FROM somewhere;
```